# MariaDb Magento 2 index large cron_schedule table

Tags: mysql, magento, mariadb

I have an irritating problem with sending transactional emails in Magento 2 (2.2.1). The mail sometimes is not send, and i don't know why.
The problem started around 1 november and when i look in the cron_schedule table i see something strange in the index, see pictures below:

Is it normal that the index takes 12.6 Mb and can it be a possible cause of my problems? can i empty it without problems?

Also i see date created at the possible date the problem started...

[image]

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  There is nothing unusual about an 12.6MB index, except that the data is sooooo much smaller!

Comment: how do i give that command? In PhPmyadmin

Comment: Use the screen that lets you type any command.  Copy & paste the output into your question (do not use screenshot).